# Cannot rotate iText pdf content

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to rotate pdf content of a table using iText 5.0.1. The existing pdf has table content from left to write, however, I would like to generate pdf from bottom to top as the table has too many columns.

I tried using  addPageDictEntry method however, it is not available as I'm using 5.0.1. Is there any way to rotate the table?
Below is my sample code

```
    pdfDocument.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
            pdfDocument.newPage();

            font = new Font(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_BOLD,BaseFont.CP1252, 
             BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 20);
             font.setStyle(Font.BOLD);
            pdfDocument.add(new Paragraph("\n"));           
            pdfDocument.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
            p = new Paragraph("Attachment 1 \n", font); 
            p.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);

            pdfDocument.add(p);

            pdfDocument.add(new Paragraph("\n"));           
            pdfDocument.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
          PdfPTable appTable1 = Table(bf,list,doc);
            pdfDocument.add(apptransTable1);
            pdfDocument.close();
```

Comment: Have you tried with iText 5.5.13?

Comment: I'm trying to use that version, however, this project contains other classes like HTMLWorker which are not supported in that iText version.
Is there any alternative way?
thank you

Comment: XMLWorker for iText 5 or pdfHTML for iText 7